# General Network construction

Tags: windows-server-2003, router, network-printer

Im looking for some guidance in creating a home network from someone with some time and patience. It would be much appreciated.

I currently have the following materials...

- Server with OS windows 2003
- Netgear router
- Network printer
- 2 windows 7 laptops

My goal is to build the server and have it operating the network printer.

I want the server to be connected to the router so that any laptop can wirelessly print using the printer.

I also want laptops to be able to access the server and be able to store files on it. That's as basics as it needs to be.

Can anyway layout some general steps I need to complete in order to accomplish this please?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are missing here.  Plugging everything into the router, installing the printer on the server and sharing it, and putting the server and laptops all into the same workgroup do it.

Comment: Do I create a workgroup through the server?

Comment: Yeah (or you could do it properly with a domain), but what is the current situation, does any of this exist yet?

Comment: Well I don't want to create a domain because one laptop is a work laptop already on our work domain. Yeah I have it all set up I just need to configure it all now with a workgroup

Comment: It is probably best to make some headway and ask more specific questions if you get stuck - it is hard and not really [faq] to ask broad questions like this.